# calling testng.xml from main method throwing error

Tags: testng

I am  calling testng.xml from main method but it is giving error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.ITestResult.getTestContext()Lorg/testng/ITestContext;
    at atu.testng.reports.writers.CurrentRunPageWriter.getSuiteNameMapper(Unknown Source)
    at atu.testng.reports.writers.CurrentRunPageWriter.writeFailedData(Unknown Source)
    at atu.testng.reports.writers.CurrentRunPageWriter.content(Unknown Source)
    at atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener.generateCurrentRunPage(Unknown Source)
    at atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener.onFinish(Unknown Source)
    at atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener.generateReport(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1023)
    at com.eagle.automation.main.MainStart.main(MainStart.java:26)
```

Comment: Looks like you have incompatible jar's in your classpath.

Comment: I am using testng-6.2.1.jar

Comment: Hi Jens, If I run testng.xml by 'Run As TestNG Suite' then it is working fine.But I same testng.xml from main method then it is throwing error.

Comment: Hi Jens, Thanks a lot. I upgrade version of testng-6.2.1 to testng-6.8.Now, it is working fine.